# Exporting world from 1.7.9 CraftBukkit to 1.6.5 or 1.7.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Is it possible for a world generated in 1.7.9 to be exported to an earlier version, such as 1.7.2 or 1.6.5?

I am aware that people can simply copy world files into respective directories, but I am not sure how far back this applies to.

The main reason I am doing this is to use modifications from the earlier Minecraft version.

Thank you for any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Worlds are generally backwards-compatible, but it has several drawbacks:

- Generally, Blocks and Items that were introduced later in the game will simply vanish.
- 1.7.6 paved the way for name-changing by converting the player data to a new format. Downgrading will mean that everyone starts from scratch, though you can always dump your inventory into a chest, downgrade, an then grab it again.
- 1.7.2 "Changed the World" by introducing a completely new world generation. While the existing world will largely stay the same (apart from invalid blocks), any newly generated chunks will use the old world generator, which will make for ugly borders

Answer (score 0):

it would be possible to play that world as far back as you want... but any existing blocks that dont exist in the update you're moving to would be destroyed, as would any Items that dont exist in that update